# Program compiled on a VMWare machine crashes with illegal instruction when run on an Amazon server

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++

I'm compiling a program on Ubuntu 14.04.3. I then copy it to an Amazon AWS server running Ubuntu 14.04.2. Yet it instantly crashes with Illegal Instruction (it works on the source machine) with the following stacktrace from `gdb`:

```
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
...
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000093716b in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, unsigned long, int const&) ()
#1  0x0000000000706581 in _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN5abcdf6kfjg446zcadetERKSs ()
#2  0x0000000000b2abad in __libc_csu_init ()
#3  0x00007ffff7106e55 in __libc_start_main (main=0x6fa390 <main>, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe668,
    init=0xb2ab60 <__libc_csu_init>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe658)
    at libc-start.c:246
#4  0x0000000000708437 in _start ()
```

What gives? It appears they are using the same versions of libc.

Answer (score 1):

Because I am you, I was able to check your compiler flags and found the following among them:

```
-march=native
```

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559275/gcc-how-is-march-different-from-mtune):

> If you use `-march` then GCC will be free to generate instructions that work on the specified CPU, but not on (typically) earlier CPUs in the architecture family.

I went ahead and recompiled your program without `-march=native` and it ran on the Amazon server without a hitch. I am not sure why this ever worked before - perhaps because you switched from VirtualBox to VMWare, which upgraded the local VM's processor capabilities beyond that of the Amazon server's, which caused `-march=native` to start generating incompatible code.

Continuing with that answer, you can alternatively try `-mtune` for a safe way to optimize the program:

> If you use `-mtune`, then the compiler will generate code that works on any of them, but will favour instruction sequences that run fastest on the specific CPU you indicated.

Comment: "Because I am you" :) I first though you were sarcastic and implicitly suggesting to OP that his question was incomplete, forcing you to guess things.

Comment: Yesterday during my excersise on the threadmill, the threadmill abruptly stopped. What happened? Answer - static from my pants discharged on the mill and caused it to reboot (true story, btw). Now I want your upvotes for the very useful insight!

Comment: @SergeyA: Hah funny story actually :). I realize the question doesn't stand on its own but I think the question + answer pair could be helpful to someone else in the future. Imagine someone (like my past self) googles "illegal instruction" and comes across this page. No upvotes required.