# tflite_diff_example_test fails to invoke interpreter

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've been trying TensorFlow lite and I've been having issues with the detection on Android so I'm trying to test my .pb and .tflite models to see if there is a difference with tflite_diff_example_test

I've retrained a mobilenet_v1_100_224 that I converted to .tflite

I'm running on MacOS 10.13.3 the following:

```
bazel build tensorflow/contrib/lite/testing/tflite_diff_example_test.cc
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/testing/tflite_diff_example_test --tensorflow_model=../new_training_dir/retrainedMNetV1_6_8000steps.pb --tflite_model=../new_training_dir/retrainedMNetV1_6_8000steps.tflite
```

And I get the following output:

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.2 AVX
Failed to invoke interpreter
Failed to invoke interpreter
...
Failed to invoke interpreter
Num errors: 100
```

I don't know where the problem is coming from

Comment: as error suggests, mabye your mac doesn't support sse4.2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917280/mac-osx-minumum-support-sse-version