# How to use Tensorflow model comparison with tflite_diff_example_test

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-lite

I have trained a model for detection, which is doing great when embedded in tensorflow sample app. 
After freezing with `export_tflite_ssd_graph` and conversion to tflite using toco the results do perform rather bad and have a huge "variety".

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50767869/9899852) answer on a similar problem with loss of accuracy I wanted to try tflite_diff_example_test on a tensorflow docker machine.

As the documentation is not that evolved right now, I build the tool referencing [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51126911/9899852) 
 
using: 
 `bazel build tensorflow/contrib/lite/testing/tflite_diff_example_test.cc` which ran smooth.

---

After figuring out all my needed input parameters I tried the testscript with following commands:

```
~/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/68a62076e91007a7908bc42a32e4cff9/external/bazel_tools/tools/test/test-setup.sh tensorflow/contrib/lite/testing/tflite_diff_example_test '--tensorflow_model=/tensorflow/shared/exported/tflite_graph.pb' '--tflite_model=/tensorflow/shared/exported/detect.tflite' '--input_layer=a,b,c,d' '--input_layer_type=float,float,float,float' '--input_layer_shape=1,3,4,3:1,3,4,3:1,3,4,3:1,3,4,3' '--output_layer=x,y'
```

and

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/testing/tflite_diff_example_test --tensorflow_model="/tensorflow/shared/exported/tflite_graph.pb" --tflite_model="/tensorflow/shared/exported/detect.tflite" --input_layer=a,b,c,d --input_layer_type=float,float,float,float --input_layer_shape=1,3,4,3:1,3,4,3:1,3,4,3:1,3,4,3 --output_layer=x,y
```

---

Both ways are failing. Errors:

1. way:

   `tflite_diff_example_test.cc:line 1: /bazel: Is a directory
   tflite_diff_example_test.cc: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token '('
   tflite_diff_example_test.cc: line 3: 'Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");'
   /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/68a62076e91007a7908bc42a32e4cff9/external/bazel_tools/tools/test/test-setup.sh: line 184: /tensorflow/: Is a directory
   /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/68a62076e91007a7908bc42a32e4cff9/external/bazel_tools/tools/test/test-setup.sh: line 276: /tensorflow/: Is a directory`
2. way:

   `2018-09-10 09:34:27.650473: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
   Failed to create session. Op type not registered 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess' in binary running on d36de5b65187. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.)`tf.contrib.resampler`should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.`

I would really appreciate any help, that enables me to compare the output of two graphs using tensorflows given tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way you mentioned is the correct way to use `tflite_diff`. However, the object detection model containing the `TFLite_Detection_PostProcess` op cannot be run via `tflite_diff`.

`tflite_diff` runs the provided TensorFlow (`.pb`) model in the TensorFlow runtime and runs the provided TensorFlow Lite (`.tflite`) model in the TensorFlow Lite runtime. In order to run the `.pb` model in the TensorFlow runtime, all of the operations must be implemented in TensorFlow.

However, in the model you provided, the `TFLite_Detection_PostProcess` op is not implemented in TensorFlow runtime - it is only available in the TensorFlow Lite runtime. Therefore, TensorFlow cannot resolve the op. Therefore, you unfortunately cannot use the `tflite_diff` tool with this model.

Comment: Alright, this seems plausible, thanks. I have not questioned the pb model I have created on my way to a tflite graph. I will generate another pb using `export_inference_graph` instead. Then I should be able to compare the trained models.