# How to specify specific SSE level to differnet source files when compiling Apple universal binary?

Tags: c++, cmake, apple-m1, intrinsics, universal-binary

In our product, we have a DSP part that is:

- in x86, it is compiled with a series of different SIMD versions (at runtime it uses the supported version determined by `cpuid`);
- in arm64, it is compiled against armv8 neon.

The CMake code controlling the build looks like this:

```
if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "arm64")
    add_library(dsp_neon STATIC neon_impl.cpp)
else()
    add_library(dsp_sse3 STATIC sse3_impl.cpp)
    add_library(dsp_sse41 STATIC sse41_impl.cpp)
    add_library(dsp_avx1 STATIC avx1_impl.cpp)
    add_library(dsp_avx2 STATIC avx2_impl.cpp)
    target_compile_options(dsp_sse3 PRIVATE -msse3)
    target_compile_options(dsp_sse41 PRIVATE -msse4.1)
    target_compile_options(dsp_avx1 PRIVATE -mavx)
    target_compile_options(dsp_avx2 PRIVATE -mavx2 -mfma)
endif()
```

Now we are trying to create Mac universal binary by specifying `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=arm64;x86_64`, and the problem comes: it seems I should add all source files into compile, and let compiler to generate corresponding machine code. However it claims massive conflicts when compiling these platform-specific sources, because ARM target don't support Intel's SIMD header files (surely it won't).

I want to make clear that:

- What is the underlying process of compiling into universal binary? Is it actually compiled twice - one time in ARM and one time in x86? If so, should I use platform macros to mask out platform-specific codes?
- Is it still valid to specify `-mxxx` when compiling universal binaries?

Comment: For a Mac universal binary, you can assume Intel CPUs, so you should use `-march=haswell` instead of just `-mavx2 -mfma` (without `-mbmi2` and other useful options, and more importantly without `-mtune=haswell`).

Comment: MacOS has support for making an `x86_64h` "slice" in a fat binary that runs on Haswell CPUs, [according to Stephen Canon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917280/what-is-the-minimum-supported-sse-flag-that-can-be-enabled-on-macos#comment78801833_45921250).  I don't if this still works as part of a universal binary, like baseline + haswell slices for x86, and also an ARM64 part.