# Find common minimum CPU features to expect when targeting a certain macOS deployment target

Tags: macos, cpu-architecture, avx, instruction-set, avx2

When building applications for macOS, it's common to specify a certain macOS version as minimum deployment target for that application. Every macOS version specifies, which are the minimal required Mac models. That way, one can expect that if a certain macOS deployment target is chosen, the application won't run on older hardware – officially unsupported trickery from the user side taken aside.

In my particular case, I have an application with a 10.14 deployment target and I wonder if I can expect that all the supported Intel Macs for that deployment target will have a CPU supporting AVX2. If that would be the case, I could get rid of dynamic dispatching code that performs runtime checks to figure out if the AVX2 code path would be suitable.

I find it quite hard to get clear information if I can expect some minimal CPU features among all supported devices for a certain macOS deployment target. I could go and manually check all the supported devices for their hardware specs, but that would be a big task and might not be worth it. So I'm looking for some kind of database that could already contain that information in a structured way or some other documentation that could give a clear answer to the AVX2 related question in particular but also other CPU features in general. Is there any?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Microarchitecture_levels / [What is the minimum supported SSE flag that can be enabled on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45917280) - note the possibility to ship an `x86_64h` slice, which is `-march=x86-64-v3` (AVX2+FMA+BMI2 = Haswell baseline).  So even if you discover you might need a fallback for some hardware you want to support, newer hardware can use the faster binary at just a cost in file size.