# gfortran equivalent of the -native flag

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I am trying to run the makefile of a program in Fortran 77 that I did not write.

It specifies the following flags:

```
FLT_FLAGS = -native -libmil
```

and then uses them to compile a Fortran 77 program:

```
f77 -O -native -libmil -c a2.f
```

but fails:

> ```
> f77: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-native’
> makefile:107: recipe for target 'vg.a(a2.o)' failed
> make: *** [vg.a(a2.o)] Error 1
> ```

The only thing I have been able to find with respect to this issue is that -native is obsolete, and maybe that's why gfortran (f77) does not recognize it: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37076/aevft.html#scrolltoc

Comment: Wait, so which compiler do you use, Oracle or gfortran? What does `f77 -v` print? How do you call gfortran? There is nothing like a Fortran native flag, every compiler has its own flags.

Comment: See the -mtune and -march flags for GCC (including gfortran) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559275/gcc-how-is-march-different-from-mtune

Comment: @VladimirF `f77 -v` prints `COLLECT_GCC=f77
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with:` [...] `Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) `. I haven't seen any license on the code I am using because a professor gave it to me. The code comes from: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.168405 and I don't know if I should publish it here for the community to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using gfortran version 5.4. I wouldn't call `f77` but `gfortran` directly if I were you.

The correct gfortran option similar to `-native` in some other compilers is `-march=native` or `-mtune=native`. See the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and [GCC: how is march different from mtune?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559275/gcc-how-is-march-different-from-mtune)

Don't forget to use other optimization flags like `-O2` or `-O3`. The native option alone is not too useful.

Comment: Unfortuntelly this is not how this site works. Take a food reaad of [ask] and [mcve]. You must describe your errors and give steps to reproduce them *inside the question itself*. If they are new errors you should ask a *new question*.